# Page Active/Deactive in wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

How can Page or Post Active/Deactive in admin side so front side display or not in wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Make check according to particular Page , Post Id, Making page as Draft is not the best way .You can make check for page url in header.php file If that particular page or post Id comes into url then automatically will be redirected to home page or the page you want .

Secondly You can also make a menu Where you will not display page in Menu.

Comment: Ok thanks that is done and also right posibility as make menu

Answer (score 0):

You can change status of any page or blog post in WP to "Draft". Then it disappears for the normal visitors.